# What kind of object is this?

Tags: botany

I'm unsure whether to call it a fruit or a vegetable. I found it on the road in a neighborhood and decided to pick it up before a car squashed it. (Thus, my initial guess was a squash.)[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be a Papaya, thus a fruit, an outline of your geographical location would be helpful to determine it.